# Mongoose select an object in Array with specific property

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

From this 'houses' collection

```
{
  _id: "0",
  rooms: [
    {
      roomName: "living-room"
      chairs: "6"
    },

    {
      roomName: "kitchen"
      chairs: "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find the house with _id = 0, and select only
the 'chairs' from the "living-room" so that the result looks like this:

```
{
  chairs: 6
}
```

I think of something that looks like this:
`House.findOne({_id: '0'}).select('rooms.chairs') // but only from {roomName: "living-room"}`
How do I complete the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
db.houses.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: "0" } },
   {
      $project: {
         chairs: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$rooms",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.roomName", "living-room"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $replaceRoot: {
         newRoot: {
            chairs: { $arrayElemAt: ["$chairs.chairs", 0] }
         }
      }
   },
])
```

Comment: Fantastic! I applied this to my situation and it works! Therefore I mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.house.findOne({"rooms.chairs":"6"},{"rooms.$":1})
```

Comment: To clarify more, the point of the query should be to find and select only `chairs`, and not query by it's value